# How to check the application in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have two Android apps that I'm calling "appClient" and "appServer". I'm using Firebase authentication to register and further log in on both apps, but a user registered on appClient cannot log in on appServer and vice versa. So I found a way to differentiate those users calling a Firebase Function every time a new user is registered and including Custom Claims to them. Here is the Custom Claims documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

I'm using this code

```
// On sign up.
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // Check if user meets role criteria.
  if ("how to check if the incoming user came from appClient or appServer???") {
    const customClaims = {
      client: true
    };
    // Set custom user claims on this newly created user.
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims)
      .then(() => {
        // Update real-time database to notify client to force refresh.
        const metadataRef = admin.database().ref("metadata/" + user.uid);
        // Set the refresh time to the current UTC timestamp.
        // This will be captured on the client to force a token refresh.
        return metadataRef.set({refreshTime: new Date().getTime()});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
});
```

But I didn't find a way to check from which application the new user came.
Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible to determine which app a user was using when the account was created.  The only inputs to an auth onCreate type function are the two arguments of type [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html) and [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userbuilder#context:-eventcontext).

If you look through the properties of those objects thoroughly, you will see nothing that discerns the app.  You'll need to find another way of setting up the custom claims, perhaps by passing the user's UID and some identifying data into an HTTP or callable type function.

Comment: Thanks Doug! Yeah I think you're right, I tried to search deep in the firebase code but I didn't find anything, so sad. I hope for firebase implement this in the future, it can save a lot of time.

Comment: Feel free to file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support